# IFS=';' read -a array not splitting ";" correctly when input contains newlines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using PHP and trying to send to a shell script a single string that includes multiple commands separated by ";" (and maybe newline).

However, the splitting is not working as expected from IFS.

My input is

```
"mycommand1 '    hello word \n    ';\nmycommand2 'hello world;\nmycommand3 'bye world;\n"
```

But for some reason it is only saving the first line inside CMDS_ARR

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMANDS="mycommand1 '    hello word 
    ';
mycommand2 'hello world;
mycommand3 'bye world;
"

# Delimit single-line commands by ";" into multi commands
# array $CMDS_ARR to include all commands as single input
IFS=';' read -ra CMDS_ARR <<< "$COMMANDS"

for CMD in "${CMDS_ARR[@]}"; do
    printf "THE COMMAND: *$CMD*\n"
done
```

Output

```
THE COMMAND: *mycommand1 '    hello word*
```

Comment: If your input actually contains a newline (and not the digraph `\n`), `read` only reads up to the space after `\n`; it never sees the `;` and word-splitting is never even performed. Please provide a *complete* example that includes an assignment to `COMMANDS` which we can use to reproduce your behavior.

Comment: What you say makes sense. Should remove the newlines before passing to IFS? This is the input I am testing. "wp option update key1 'ohhh there was a  tt     x      ya wala xde  aleeek \\n          ';\nwp option update key2 '    this                is             bro        xxx     ';\nwp option update key3 'ohmylov  freakout e';\nwp option update key5 'stam    t yyey   ';\n"

Comment: Does my edit capture the value of `$COMMANDS` correctly?

Comment: Can the commands contain newlines? Your comment shows `\\n` instead of `\n` inside the first command. It's a lot easier to parse the command list if there are only newlines between commands and not inside of them.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used by the shell itself; user-defined variables should use lower-case characters to avoid potential for conflicts. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable. (*The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*)

Comment: You could also avoid relying on `IFS` at all, and use `while IFS= read -r -d ';' command; do echo "Processing $command"; done` to read one command per invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-d` option to set the "newline" character to a null byte, so that `read` sees the entire input as a single line.

```
IFS=';' read -d '' -ra CMDS_ARR <<< "$COMMANDS"
```

To avoid a non-zero exit status when the only problem is the missing null byte to terminate the input, don't use a here string (which *cannot* contain a null byte). One option, per @CharlesDuffy:

```
IFS=';' read -d '' -ra cmds_arr < <( printf '%s\0' "$COMMANDS" )
```

A *variable* or hard-coded string cannot contain a null byte, but the output of `printf` can.

Comment: Worth noting that this will have a nonzero exit status -- one should take care around that if running with `set -e` or an `ERR` trap. (`IFS=';' read -d '' -ra array < <(printf '%s\0' "$string")` would also negate the issue, by NUL-terminating the input).

Comment: it is worth adding your comment to the answer above. Thanks.